# Why can't both args and keyword only arguments be mixed with *args and **kwargs simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, args, keyword-argument

The usage of *args and **kwargs in python is clear to me and there are many questions out there in SO (eg [Use of *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs) and [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)).

But one thing I would like to understand is: why is it not possible to simultaneously define mandatory positional args, mandatory kwarg arguments and eventually still allow catching other args and kwargs as in `cant_do_that` below?

```
def one_kwarg_is_mandatory(*, b, **kwargs):
    print(b)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print(key, value)    
        
def one_pos_arg_and_one_kwarg_are_mandatory(a, *, b, **kwargs):
    print(a, b)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print(key, value)
      
# I wanted a mandatory arg (a) and possibly parse other args (*args), 
# then a mandatory kwarg (b) and eventually other kwargs (**kwargs)
def cant_do_that(a, *args, *, b, **kwargs):
    print(a, b)
    print(args)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print(key, value)

# not really interested on this because "b" must be a kwarg and hiding 
# it under **kwargs would not be explicit enough for my customer (sometimes myself ;))
def could_do_this_but(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    print(a, b)
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

Yes one could get rid of `b` in the `could_do_this_but` function's signature, perform (for instance) a `kwargs.get("b", None)` at the top of the function and raise some appropriate error if found `None`... but having "b" directly on the function signature would allow faster and more explicit code development employing the function down the road.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct syntax is `def cant_do_that(a, *args, b, **kwargs):`. Note that `*` is used only once, *both* to mark the end of positional arguments *and* to set the name for variadic positional arguments.

---

The `*` in a [function definition is syntactically unique](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) at the separation between positional-or-keyword and keyword-only arguments:

```
parameter_list_starargs   ::=  "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," ["**" parameter [","]]]
                               | "**" parameter [","]
```

In short, the grammar `"*" [parameter]` means `*` and `*args` are syntactically the same thing – a literal `*` and optional name – which may occur only once. Use a bare `*` to start keyword-only arguments *without* taking variadic positional arguments, and use a named `*args` to start keyword-only arguments *with* taking variadic positional arguments.

> If the form “`*identifier`” is present, it is initialized to a tuple
> receiving any excess positional parameters, defaulting to the empty
> tuple. [...] Parameters after “`*`” or “`*identifier`” are keyword-only
> parameters and may only be passed used keyword arguments.